# markup logic between two period

Tags: php, mysql

I have a markup table that have field like below

```
id     markup      from_date        to_date 
  1     5          2013-01-20       2013-01-31
  2     10         2013-02-01       2013-01-20
```

Now if I select date from   20 Jan - to 5 Feb then I should get Average markup

```
Ex-  20 jan to 24 Jan is 5 markup for 5 days
     and 25 jan 4 fen is 10 markup for 10 days
```

so average markup i will get 8.3%

Comment: I'm not sure you can/want to do this in SQL, what programming language are you using (apart from the obvious SQL).

Comment: i am using php and mysql

Comment: how come the average boil downs to 6.6 ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak sorry it was 8.3 ..

Comment: for 5 days 5% and for 10 days  10*10    (5*5+10*10)/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with data and calculations in your example.

Anyway here is a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e2c0/15)

```
select sum(markup*days)/sum(days)
from
(
select Markup,
 LEAST
 ( DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date)+1,
   GREATEST(DATEDIFF('2013-02-05',from_date)+1,0),
   GREATEST(DATEDIFF(to_date,'2013-01-20')+1,0)
 ) days
from t
where from_date between '2013-01-20' and '2013-02-05'
      or 
      to_date between '2013-01-20' and '2013-02-05'
) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there seem to be few errors with your question.

1. Why is from_date once less than, and then greater than the to_date ? ( used ABS function to get
   number of days)
2. Assumed your average is   Total of markup divided by total of days.

This is the query that would give you the desired response :

```
SELECT Sum(markup) / Sum(num_days) AS the_average
FROM   (SELECT id,
               markup,
               from_date,
               to_date,
               Abs (Timestampdiff(day, from_date, to_date)) AS num_days
        FROM   test) AS t;
```